# Removing google map markers using JQuery

Tags: jquery, google-maps, mapping

I've searched hi and low for info regarding this but to no avail.

Basically I have a page that is loading a bunch of cateories as checkboxes, for example checkbox 1 is called 'Exhibitions' and when clicked on displays all the exhibitions on the map (I am passing the value of the checkbox to the JQuery function which then filters the XML). I have 6 checkboxes all relating to different categories. I have this part all working well but I now need to remove these markers when the checkbox is unticked. I also need it to only remove the markers associated with that category.

Code is below:

```
MYMAP.placeMarkersTest = function(filename, CatValue) {
$.get(filename, function(xml) {
    $(xml).find("marker").each(function() {

        var eventCat = $(this).find('Category').text();

        if (eventCat == CatValue) {
            var name = $(this).find('name').text();
            var address = $(this).find('name').text();


            var lat = $(this).find('lat').text();
            var lng = $(this).find('lng').text();
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lng));

            MYMAP.bounds.extend(point);

            var icon = "/images/mapping/EventsIcon.png";

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: point,
                icon: icon,
                map: MYMAP.map
            });

            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var html = '<strong>' + name + '</strong><br />';
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(html);
                infoWindow.open(MYMAP.map, marker);
            });
            MYMAP.map.fitBounds(MYMAP.bounds);


        } else {
            //alert("There are no matches");
        }
    });
});
}
```

Any ideas on how to remove the specific markers would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When creating your markers you can add the category it belongs to as a property using marker.Set('MyProperty', 'MyCategory')  then add the markers to a global array.  When you are ready to remove the markers you can loop through the marker array and call marker.setMap(null) to remove it from the map.

```
var markers = new Array(); 

function setMarkers(map, locations, category) {
        for(var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            var area = locations[i];
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(area.Location[0], area.Location[1]);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                shadow: markerShadow,
                icon: markerImage,
                shape: markerShape,
                title: area.Name
            });
            marker.set('category', category);
            markers.push(marker);
        }
    }

function clearMarkers(category) {
    for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          if (markers[i].get('category') == category) {
            markers[i].setMap(null);
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, that looks like an ideal solution. I will give it a go!

Comment: Just thought I'd mention I have a fiddle with the code and got it to work perfectly, thanks jacksonakj

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding each marker to a global array so its stored in context and using Map.removeOverlay(markerArray[indexvalue]) to remove it?